# How to implement ACID transactions on a custom key-value store

Tags: c#, .net, distributed, key-value

I have a server which exposes its storage similar to file system - it has files, folders, and you can upload files, download files, copy, move, delete, etc. There is absolutely no way to modify the server's interface (imagine FTP). There is also a limit for file name length.

I have multiple clients that need to use this storage simultaneously. The only means for them to communicate is through this file system interface. No custom central server for synchronization or peer-to-peer is allowed.

How can I implement remote key-value store from client-side, capable of ACID transactions, using this server's interface as a backend? Multiple clients can be accessing/modifying the key-value store at the same time, and the locking mechanism should be implemented only with the use of the exposed server file system interface.

I can easily turn that file system into custom key-value store, so what I really need is some **`C#/.NET`** library that adds transactions to an arbitrary key-value store. I don't need Facebook/Google-style performance, the key-value store will be used to save only dozens of GBs.

---

Suppose a remote key-value store allows me to `string get(id)`, `void put(id, string)`, and `delete(id)` entries. No other information is obtainable from the server (even no exceptions are thrown on errors). Given that the only clients accessing the store will be mine, how should I implement them such that only one can write/delete at the same time (write-locking)? Given the very very limited server interface, is it even possible? I suppose the solution would require some very nice cryptographic trick, but I haven't been able to come up with anything that would work yet.

---

### Resources

- As an inspiration, [Distributed locks with Redis](http://redis.io/topics/distlock) seems quite interesting

Comment: How can you ensure ACID(ity) on the data stored on server form the client-side?

Comment: @codelion that is what i want to figure out ... there might be a way to implement some messaging system in that key-value store, so the clients can synchronize (and implement locks with the help of timeouts etc), but i dont want to reinvent the wheel

Comment: How can locks help if the underlying filesystem itself does not guarantee ACID properties ?

Comment: well it can help implement atomicity ... and as suggested by my post, I have the same questions as you, and I am looking for a solution. That's what my post is about.

Comment: Just as a clarification, I control the source code of all the clients. Thus with a smart approach, there might be a way to make the storage ACID from client-side perspective, because all the clients can follow the same protocol.

Comment: Is the storage you are storing to NTFS or some other file system that has hooks that can be called from [`System.Transactions.Transaction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Unfortunately no :-( It's a RESTful remote service.

Comment: Does the service have a `move` or `rename` operation that can overwrite an existing file without ever having the destination file ever be in a inconsistent state? Also can you get the metadata "Last write time" for the files?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Luckily with my current storage, I can do that, but the storage API is volatile and only the reduced API of `get-content`/`put-content`/`delete` is guaranteed. However, out of curiosity, how would you implement lock with a `move` and `last write time`? (Given unpredictable network lag.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a rough idea but you basically need to implement a "[Copy on Write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write)"  functionality wherein when you go to modify a file you would copy the file to a identical file name with a special extension, this would represent your working file you write your changes to and also represents your "lock". If someone detects that the "lock file" exists they can check the last write time to the lock file and if the last write is older than a pre-set timeout the lock can be assumed to be abandoned and delete the lock, if the last write is not older than the timeout access to the file is blocked.

When a client is done modifying the copied version of the file it renames the file back to the original "non locked" filename overwriting the unmodified original copy in a single atomic operation.

This gives you everything that is required for ACID with the only exception being **D**urability in that an abandoned lock takes a timeout period to be detected as abandoned.

If you did not have access to last write times from the files you could still use this structure but you would need to add a 3rd "metadata" file to represent the lock instead of your "in progress" copy of the file. That metadata file would just hold the timestamp of the lock's creation as its content.

Comment: But this only works if the `copy` method fails in case the destination file already exists. If it doesn't fail, then 2 or more clients can think they have the lock at the same time, right? And in case where I use unique destination filename (for the copy operation) for each client, then if several clients are trying to take the lock at the same time, then 1 or more clients may succeed (because of the time delay between checking for a lock file and copying).

Comment: You are correct. You would need a unique filename per client. the procedure for taking a lock would be Check, Create Lock, Check for concurrent lock, rollback if concurrent lock and retry after a random interval.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work in all cases I can think of (unless for deadlocks caused by random intervals...). However, this approach requires that the clients know each other upfront. In case they do not know each other upfront, and they can come anytime and disappear without notification anytime, how would you reliably publish and unpublish (timeout) their presence?

Comment: I don't see where the need for the clients to know about each other is. The "lock format" could be `OriginalFileName.ext.{Client Guid}.lck` all the client needs to do is walk the file name backwards. Check to see if there is a `*.lck` then check to see if the client guid is the client's own guid. If it is its own guid it can ignore it, if it is someone else's guid it checks the age of the file aginst the timeoout to see if the lock is abandoned. If the lock is abandoned it deletes the lock then restarts the process from the start.

Comment: Oh well that assumes there is a function like `GetFirstFile/GetNextFile` or something like that, to list the files ... I was thinking among the lines of `get_content`, `set_content` and `delete` interface without any `get_ids`...

Answer (score 0):

You may use ZoneTree, (https://github.com/koculu/ZoneTree)
a persistent, high-performance, transactional, and ACID-compliant key-value database for .NET.

It supports Timestamp-based Concurrency Control.
The algorithm is explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp-based_concurrency_control

OptimisticZoneTree converts non-transactional ZoneTree (LSM  Tree) into ACID-compliant key-value store.

You may extract the transaction implementation (https://github.com/koculu/ZoneTree/tree/main/src/ZoneTree/Transactional) to transform your custom key-value store ACID-compliant.